# sbt.Resolve Exception : unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin 2.4.0 not found

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

Installed Scala Language : 2.11.7
Scala SBT : 0.13.9

I started scala project in a folder MySample and created `build.sbt` and given below commands

```
name := "File Searcher"   

version :="0.1" 

scalaVersion :="2.11.7"
```

And then created folder Project and created `build.properties` file and added below code

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

And then in the same Project Folder  created `plugins.sbt` file and added below code

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse -plugin" % "2.4.0")
```

and ran the below command in command window

> D:\Demo\MySample>sbt eclipse
>
> Getting below error :  [error]<*update>sbt.ResolveException:
>   unresolved dependency:
>   com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.1: not found Project
>   Loading failed : etry,uit

I tried that command with 2.5.0 , 2.3.0 etc trial and error but couldn't figure that out

All answers are sayting sbteclipse ect Do I need to insatll separately SBTECLIPSE plugin? If so provide any URL

[Error From Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPBNX.png)

Comment: `"sbteclipse -plugin"` is that a typo here or do you have that erroneous space character in your `.sbt` file? It also helps if you format your question so that file contents and error messages are shown monospaced (indent by four spaces). Remove '??????' if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to the latest and greatest:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

See https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse for up to date version information.

Comment: this actually worked for me - the last version changes though, it's "5.2.3" at this time, check the link

Answer (score 0):

Added this line in plugins.sbt

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")

this worked for me.